# Sharing MacBook internet to iPad via USB

Tags: macos, ipad, catalina, internet, tethering

I was sharing my MacBook LAN connection to my iPad using the internet sharing feature. But after the most recent update, I cannot find the iPad USB and iPhone USB option to share the internet. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: After the most recent update of what?  iOS?  macOS?  Both?  What are the current versions?

Comment: My Macbook is on macOS Catalina v10.15.4 and my iPad is on 13.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I had to first connect the USB cable between the MacBook and iPad before a prompt came up, requesting me to install some updates, before the iPad USB option came up